# How can I animate the sun in Sky Texture?

Tags: animation

I'm trying to keyframe the Sun Elevation and Sun Rotation from the Sky Texture Node but it doesn't work.

I'm setting at frame 1: Elevation 15, Position 1, and at frame 200: Elevation 50, Position 100.

When I click play, the Elevation and Position are set at about 70 and 160 and they are fixed. I guess they have something to do with the Sun position tab which tries to get the real status of the sun based on day/month/year, latitude/longitude, time, etc. Sadly I can't find a way to animate those variables.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Animating in most parameters on blender is done by hovering over the value and pressing the letter <kbd>I</kbd> to insert a keyframe (or right click and choose to add a keyframe), then move to a different frame, change the value and add another keyframe.

[image]

Comment: You can also click on the dot on the right of the field to add a keyframe